# Is it possible to store class data into an array in Python, then randomly pick a class from the array?

Tags: python, arrays, class, random

```
enemyArray = [Ork, Goblin]

class Ork:

    name = "Mountain Dweller"`
    health = 10
    armor = 1
    damage = 5


class Goblin:

    name = "Looter"
    health = 5
    armor = 0
    damage = 5
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: I think the answer is yes.  Why don't you try it first and let us know where you have trouble?

Comment: Why don't you just try it yourself, it's literally like 20 seconds.

Comment: You are not working with an array... you have a `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, make sure you declare the classes first:

```
import random

class Ork:
    name = "Mountain Dweller"
    health = 10
    armor = 1
    damage = 5

class Goblin:
    name = "Looter"
    health = 5
    armor = 0
    damage = 5

enemyArray = [Ork, Goblin]

for _ in range(8):
    print(random.choice(enemyArray))
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.Ork'>
<class '__main__.Goblin'>
<class '__main__.Goblin'>
<class '__main__.Goblin'>
<class '__main__.Goblin'>
<class '__main__.Goblin'>
<class '__main__.Ork'>
<class '__main__.Ork'>
```

Comment: Wish I had more reputation so I could up vote this. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Justikun You're welcome. You can accept answers to your questions with the check near the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import choice

list_ = [Ork, Goblin]

rand_enemy = random.choice(list_)
```